# Set default value for remaining size of list by use of Java 8 and Stream

Tags: java, stream, hash-map

I have written a method which will return the size 16 List every time. If the input List has size less than 16, the remaining list object will be filled with default values.  Is there any way to remove the if and for condition from the `enrichAddress` method?.

```
@Component
public class TestService{

public List<TestB> enrichAddress(List<TestA> cardAccountDetails) {
if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(cardAccountDetails)) return Collections.emptyList();

List<TestB> testBList = cardAccountDetails.stream().map(AccountService::buildAddress).collect(Collectors.toList());
if (testBList.size() < 16) {
  int accountCounts = testBList.size();
  for (; accountCounts < 16; accountCounts++) {
    testBList.add(buildDefaultAddress());
  }
}
return testBList;
}

private TestA buildDefaultAddress() {
TestA testA = new TestA();


testA.setA("NONE");
testA.setAccS("TEST_STATUS");

testA.setAccT("TEST_ACCOUNT_TYPE");
testA.setADes("");

return testA;
}

private static TestA buildAddress(TestB testB) {
TestA testA = new TestA();

testA.setDes(testB.getDes());
testA.setAcc(testB.getAcN());
testA.setAccSt(testB.getAccS());

testA.setAccT(testB.getAcCT());
testA.setAc(testB.getAct());

return testA;
 }
}
```

Comment: "if": just leave it out, then the loop will iterate 0 times. "for": not without making the code an unreadable mess.

Comment: aside - you are not really handling the more than 16 cases either, related to a stricter requirement *return the size 16 List every time*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mtj already mentioned in the comment, adding stream trickery to fulfill this need only makes the code less readable. Streams are nifty, exciting and popular but they are not always the right tool for the job. Sometimes a plain loop is still the best choice.

The common pattern in padding a collection (well, most often it's a string that gets padded) to certain size is to use a while loop. It has least amount of excess variables and code and the syntax communicates intent quite naturally ("while size is less than 16, do this"). But this still only tells that you are intentionally padding the collection to 16 elements. You also need to document in comments the reason *why* you are padding the collection to 16 elements.

```
List<Address> addresses = cardAccountDetails
    .stream()
    .map(AccountService::buildAddress)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

while (addresses.size() < 16) {
    addresses.add(buildDefaultAddress());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While I do agree with the others that a loop is the simpler solution in this situation, I'd nevertheless like demonstrate a `Stream` solution, because IMO the noted disadvantages are not due to streams and functional programming in general, but due to Java's limited concept and implementations of streams.

A functional way would be extend the stream of converted addresses with an "infinite" stream of default addresses and then cut that stream off at 16:

```
Stream<Address> addressStream = cardAccountDetails.stream().map(AccountService::buildAddress);
Stream<Address> defaultAddressStream = Stream.generate(AccountService::buildDefaultAddress);

return Stream.concat(addressStream, defaultAddressStream).limit(16).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you are interested in more realistic functional programming you could try one of several functional libraries which allow a more concise and readable syntax. For example with [vavr.io](https://vavr.io):

```
return Stream.ofAll(cardAccountDetails) // Creates a io.vavr.collections.Stream
  .map(AccountService::buildAddress)
  .extend(AccountService::buildDefaultAddress)
  .take(16)
  .collect(Collectors.toList()); // Converts back to a regular Java List
```

Instead of converting back to a Java `List` you could just use vavr colletions through out your project.